# GridBag Layout acting as a flow layout , within a card layout. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, grid, layout-manager

This code uses the card layout, as I want to change the window display rather than have multiple windows (or frames). Therefore I want multiple panels, which seems to work.

However within the panels I want to use the gridbag layout for positioning components. But it's not working! It acts as a flow layout. Can anyone help me get over this hurdle? Please.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class another
 {
private JPanel contentPane;
private MyPanel panel1;
private MyPanel2 panel2;

private void displayGUI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();


    contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    panel1 = new MyPanel(contentPane);
    panel2 = new MyPanel2();
    contentPane.add(panel1, "Panel 1"); 
    contentPane.add(panel2, "Panel 2");
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.pack();   
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String... args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new another().displayGUI();
        }
    });
}
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextField How;
private JLabel jcomp2;
private JLabel jcomp3;
private JButton jcomp4;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel myPanel1;

public MyPanel(JPanel panel) 
{

    contentPane = panel;
    //construct components
    How = new JTextField (1);
    jcomp2 = new JLabel ("Label2");
    jcomp3 = new JLabel ("Label3");
    jcomp4 = new JButton ("openNewWindow");
    myPanel1 = new JPanel();

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (600, 600));
    setLayout (new GridBagLayout());

    //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
    /*
    How.setBounds (245, 50, 60, 25);
    jcomp2.setBounds (35, 30, 185, 50);
    jcomp3.setBounds (250, 30, 60, 20);
    jcomp4.setLocation(0, 0);
    jcomp4.setSize(315, 25);
    */




   insert(jcomp2, 0, 0, 1, 1); 
   insert(jcomp3, 0, 1, 1, 1); 
   insert(jcomp4, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    jcomp4.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
            cardLayout.next(contentPane);
        }
    });

    //add components
    //add (How);
    add (jcomp2);
   add (jcomp3);
   add (jcomp4);               
}


public void insert(Component c, int gridX, int gridY, int gridW, int gridH)
{

  GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

  constraint.gridx = gridX;
  constraint.gridy = gridY;
  constraint.gridwidth = gridW;
  constraint.gridheight = gridH;

  constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
  myPanel1.add(c, constraint);

}



}

class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
private JButton jcomp1;
private JButton jcomp2;
private JButton jcomp3;
private JTextField jcomp4;

public MyPanel2() {
    //construct components
    jcomp1 = new JButton ("test1");
    jcomp2 = new JButton ("test2");
    jcomp3 = new JButton ("test3");
    jcomp4 = new JTextField (5);

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (395, 156));
    setLayout (null);

    //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
    jcomp1.setBounds (20, 45, 100, 25);
    jcomp2.setBounds (135, 60, 100, 25);
    jcomp3.setBounds (260, 35, 100, 25);
    jcomp4.setBounds (105, 115, 100, 25);

    //add components
    add (jcomp1);
    add (jcomp2);
    add (jcomp3);
    add (jcomp4);       
}
}
```

Comment: What overall GUI appearance are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I ideally want to create a content section, which changes display dependent upon what button is pressed. On each window a heading remains the same.

Comment: Then the main GUI uses BorderLayout, the title is held in the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` location and the JPanel that uses CardLayout is held in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. But that doesn't answer what your GridBagLayout JPanel is trying to achieve.

Comment: That's what I originally tried to do. I had a border layout, and not the card layout, but the gridbag layout in the center section of the border layout. I could not get the center section to change, only disappear.

Comment: I wanted to use the grid bag layout to give me control over where i positioned components, as I will have multiple components to add and use.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in this section of your code example:

Comment: class NextPanel extends JPanel {
    public NextPanel(SimpleCardExample scExample) {
        add(new JButton(new NextAction("Next", scExample)));
    }
}

class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
    private SimpleCardExample scExample;

    public NextAction(String name, SimpleCardExample scExample) {
        super(name);
        this.scExample = scExample;
        int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        scExample.nextCard();
    }
}

Comment: As you're seeing, comments don't display code in any readable way. Please edit your question, adding your pertinent code to the bottom of the code that you currently have as well as any other pertinent new information that clarifies your question for us.

Comment: Oh, you're asking about **my** code. The one class is an AbstractAction, think of it as an ActionListener "on steroids". It gives the JButton its ActionListener as well as its text, its mnemonic. It's a handy tool.

Comment: in your code, that the section I just mentioned previously, how would I position the components so that they too are using the gridbag layout?

Comment: Quite obviously by giving the JPanel a GridBagLayout and using GridBagConstraints when adding components. I don't understand the question since you seem to be familiar with setting a JPanel's layout manager.

Comment: It does not seem to work.

Comment: And I cannot stop the program from linking back to the first panel. The final panel always links back to the first panel. How is this avoided?

Comment: You're asking new questions unrelated to your original post. Your original question has been answered: you were using GridBagLayout wrong, applying it to the wrong JPanel. Let's not muddy this water too much by going too off-path. I suggest that you continue to debug your code and then if you're unable to figure things out, ask a new question, one with viable [mcve] code and move forward with it.

Answer (score 1):

You look to be unnecessarily over-complicating things. You create a JPanel called contentPane and give it a CardLayout, all well and good, but then for some reason you pass that contentPane JPanel into the MyPanel constructor,

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
panel1 = new MyPanel(contentPane); 
panel2 = new MyPanel2();
```

and then within the constructor you assign components to this same contentPane JPanel -- but why? You assign GridBagLayout to the MyPanel `this` instance, but then add components to the myPanel1 variable within it in a GridBag way when this JPanel has the JPanel default FlowLayout:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    // ....

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel myPanel1;

    public MyPanel(JPanel panel) {
        contentPane = panel;

        // ....

        myPanel1 = new JPanel();

        setLayout (new GridBagLayout()); // you set *** this *** to GridBagLayout

        insert(jcomp2, 0, 0, 1, 1); 
        insert(jcomp3, 0, 1, 1, 1); 
        insert(jcomp4, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        add (jcomp2);  // and then you add components to this without GridBagConstraints ?
        add (jcomp3);
        add (jcomp4);               
    }


    public void insert(Component c, int gridX, int gridY, int gridW, int gridH) {

        // ....

        // but then add components in a GridBagLayout way into the myPanel1 JPanel???
        myPanel1.add(c, constraint);    
    }
}
```

Better to set myPanel to use GridBagLayout:

```
    // adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    // setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    myPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Rather than `this`

Again it seems that you're over-complicating what should be a simple endeavor.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleCardExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int EB_GAP = 8;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    public SimpleCardExample() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(new GridBagPanel(this), GridBagPanel.class.getSimpleName());
        add(new NextPanel(this), NextPanel.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public void nextCard() {
        cardLayout.next(this);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleCardExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleCardExample());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class GridBagPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 6;
    private static final Insets GBC_INSETS = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);

    public GridBagPanel(SimpleCardExample scExample) {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Title Goes Here", SwingConstants.CENTER), createGbc(0, 0, 2, 1));
        add(new JLabel("Name:"), createGbc(0, 1, 1, 1));
        add(new JTextField(15), createGbc(1, 1, 1, 1));
        add(new JLabel("Phone:"), createGbc(0, 2, 1, 1));
        add(new JTextField(15), createGbc(1, 2, 1, 1));
        add(new JLabel("Address:"), createGbc(0, 3, 1, 1));
        add(new JTextField(15), createGbc(1, 3, 1, 1));
        add(new JButton(new NextAction("Next", scExample)), createGbc(0, 4, 2, 1));
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.gridwidth = w;
        gbc.gridheight = h;
        gbc.insets = GBC_INSETS;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        return gbc;
    }
}

class NextPanel extends JPanel {
    public NextPanel(SimpleCardExample scExample) {
        add(new JButton(new NextAction("Next", scExample)));
    }
}

class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
    private SimpleCardExample scExample;

    public NextAction(String name, SimpleCardExample scExample) {
        super(name);
        this.scExample = scExample;
        int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        scExample.nextCard();
    }
}
```